# React testing-library unable to re render modal in between tests

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, testing-library

I have a modal component that I am rendering for multiple tests like so:

```
const result = render(<MyModal {...myTestProps} />);
const modalComponent = screen.getByTestId('modal-client-id');
```

In one of my tests I dismiss the modal:

```
   it("Closes modal when cancel button is clicked", async(done) => {
       const result = render(<MyModal {...myTestProps} />);
       const modalComponent = screen.getByTestId('modal-client-id');
       const cancelButton = screen.getByTestId('modal-cancel-button');
       await act(async () => {
           new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
               fireEvent.click(cancelButton);
               done();
           });
       });
       expect(modalComponent).not.toBeInDocument();
   });
```

But on subsequent tests:

```
   it("Closes modal when successful", async(done) => {
       const result = render(<MyModal {...myTestProps} />);
       const modalComponent = screen.getByTestId('modal-client-id');
       const okButton = screen.getByTestId('modal-ok-button');
       await act(async () => {
           new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
               fireEvent.click(okButton);
               done();
           });
       });
       expect(modalComponent).not.toBeInDocument();
   });
```

Getting by testId fails. The only thing rendered in the document is an empty

```
//Cancel test
<DocumentFragment>
    <div />
    <div>
      ...Modal elements
    </div>
</DocumentFragment>

//Ok button
<DocumentFragment>
    <div />
</DocumentFragment>
```

I have tried adding a `[cleanup][1]`, as well as clearing/reinitializing `document`, `document.body`, and `document.innerhtml` in `afterEach` but all to no effect. The tests always run successfully when with the other commented out. The component it self is defined with React hooks, and I do not see any global side effects coming out of the modal component. Is there a way to reset the dom to alway re render the modal in subsequent tests?

Answer (score 3):

My case was that I was using act and promises incorrectly. I followed [Act warnings and tips](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/fix-the-not-wrapped-in-act-warning) and refactored the act like so:

```
   it("Closes modal when successful", async(done) => {
       const result = render(<MyModal {...myTestProps} />);
       const modalComponent = screen.getByTestId('modal-client-id');
       const okButton = screen.getByTestId('modal-ok-button');
       fireEvent.click(okButton);
       await waitForElementToBeRemoved(screen.getByTestId('modal-client-id');
       expect(modalComponent).not.toBeInDocument();
       done();
   });
```

Since I wasn't resolving the promise and incorrectly calling `done()` the rendering was causing side effects in my tests. `fireEvent` also does not need an external wrap with act as it already performs the action in an `act`.